# How do I get formatted_phone_number from this link using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my code. Why it is showing empty results? Can you spot any wrong in my code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CmRYAAAAciqGsTRX1mXRvuXSH2ErwW-jCINE1aLiwP64MCWDN5vkXvXoQGPKldMfmdGyqWSpm7BEYCgDm-iv7Kc2PF7QA7brMAwBbAcqMr5i1f4PwTpaovIZjysCEZTry8Ez30wpEhCNCXpynextCld2EBsDkRKsGhSLayuRyFsex6JA6NPh9dyupoTH3g&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyBgWOenfvzi-x7n1Xu-WLQx4ltFkuRNrhQ",
   function(data, textStatus){
      $("#placenamesss").append(data.result[0].formatted_phone_number+'<br/>');
   });
});
```

Is the correct way to do it or not? How do I get formatted_phone_number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing cross XHR requests, which won't work for security reasons. You'll have to create a proxy, like a small PHP script that will obtain the information and output it to you.

Warning, the following should be secured!!

Your PHP file (let's call it proxy.php) could look something like this:

```
<?php 

echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);

?>
```

And your jQuery, something similar to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("proxy.php?url=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CmRYAAAAciqGsTRX1mXRvuXSH2ErwW-jCINE1aLiwP64MCWDN5vkXvXoQGPKldMfmdGyqWSpm7BEYCgDm-iv7Kc2PF7QA7brMAwBbAcqMr5i1f4PwTpaovIZjysCEZTry8Ez30wpEhCNCXpynextCld2EBsDkRKsGhSLayuRyFsex6JA6NPh9dyupoTH3g&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyBgWOenfvzi-x7n1Xu-WLQx4ltFkuRNrhQ", function(data, textStatus){

        $("#placenamesss").append(data.result[0].formatted_phone_number+'<br/>');

    });
});
```

Comment: but i did not use php. so please. u do in javascript

Comment: because i want to change continousely the reference .so not possible in php.

Comment: no response.it is showing data.result is undefined
[Break On This Error] var resul= data.result.formatted_phone_number;

Comment: also showing error:{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the formatted phone number like so:

```
var number = data.result.formatted_phone_number;
```

`result` is not an array but just another object.

Comment: how get phone number using only java script, ajax and jquery.